If I create a recursion with GoTo in LibreOffice Basic, will the stack overflow?
I'm working on developing a timer that performs some action every 30 ms. I want to do this using only LibreOffice Basic. I tried creating a recursion, but the stack overflowed. I also tried using loops, but they run slower, which is noticeable even to the eye. Then my research supervisor found GoTo. Using GoTo, I want to implement a recursion. I've run this code, and the stack didn't overflow, but I'm curious if it could overflow, and if so, when? For example, the nested recursion lives for around 3-3.5k calls (I've verified this).
Sub loopWork
    GoTo Label1
Label1:
    if stateMainTimer = 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If   
    GoTo Label2
Label2:
    loopWorkVoid()
    GoTo label1
End Sub

This structure has supported over 35,000 calls.
I ran recursion without GoTo, and it holds up to about 3,000-3,500 calls before overflowing. I added a for loop, then called recursion, and that structure lasted around 20,000 calls. With this structure (GoTo), it has been holding for more than 75,000 calls already, and I'm curious about the limit.
I want to get an answer with an explanation, like why does recursion crash on 3k calls but GoTo on 30k doesn't crash, and will it even fall into recursion? What does it depend on in GoTo?

You can't create a recursion with goto. Given the task it's not even clear why you'd want to. I can't see how you'd sensibly use recursion to run a task every 30ms. The only pattern that comes to mind will, indeed, cause the stack to overflow. Loop structures should not be slower than recursion - the opposite is usually true. I suggest you step back from this, explain what you're trying to do every 30ms, and ask about that. This looks very much like an XY problem

I provided an example code where Label1 is called, and it calls Label2. Then Label2 calls Label1, and this goes around in a circle. Isn't this recursion?

Your code doesn't call anything. GOTO just jumps to a new place in the code. Recursion is a very different process.

I've commented out unnecessary lines in your code that don't do anything:
Sub loopWork
    'GoTo Label1
Label1:
    if stateMainTimer = 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If   
    'GoTo Label2
'Label2:
    loopWorkVoid()
    GoTo label1
End Sub

Now it is clearly visible that this is the while loop. The while loop runs a little faster than the for loop because there is no need for a counter. The while loop isn't a recursion, no matter how you confuse it. The recursion would be if loopWork procedure called itself or if loopWorkVoid procedure called itself.
When one procedure/function calls another procedure/function or itself, the return address is written to the stack. Recursive calls cannot continue indefinitely, as this will inevitably lead to stack overflow. That is, recursive calls must be finite. And judging by your question, you used recursion, but didn't interrupt it in any way.
Here is a quote from the documentation:

Note:
The recursion levels are set at different levels based on the software platform. For Windows the recursion level is 5800. For Solaris and Linux, an evaluation of the stacksize is performed and the recursion level is calculated.



... but GoTo on 30k doesn't crash, and will it even fall into recursion?

It is impossible to give a definite answer to this question, because you haven't shown the implementation of procedure loopWorkVoid. If procedure loopWorkVoid calls procedure loopWork, then yes, it will.


I provided an example code where Label1 is called, and it calls Label2. Then Label2 calls Label1, and this goes around in a circle. Isn't this recursion?

No. This is not a recursion. What you meant should probably look something like this (but I'm not sure if this syntax is supported in LibreOffice BASIC):
'Attention! Causes stack overflow!
Sub loopWork()
    Dim Sub2 As Action
    Dim Sub1 =
        Sub()
            'Label1
            If stateMainTimer = 2 Then Exit Sub
            Sub2()
        End Sub
    Sub2 =
        Sub()
            'Label2
            loopWorkVoid()
            Sub1()
        End Sub
    Sub1()
End Sub

